# Cook stove & plumbing vent pipes next to each other?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, vent

I am getting rid of a wood stove in my kitchen and will have a hole in my roof where the stove pipe once stood. At the same time my cook stove and sink are not currently vented (also no aav.) Would it be possible to put both vents pipes next to each other through that hole or do they need to be a certain distance from each other?

Comment: Are you sure the sink is not vented?  Most homes have at least one 3 or 4 inch main vent that all sinks/tubs/toilets vent though.  A lack of or clogged/blocked vent is the second main cause of drain problems.

Comment: Yes, I am positive. It is just a one bathroom, one kitchen sink cottage. I have had a plumber in with open walls to discuss venting but am finishing some other work first before I can have him in. Did not ask the vent question.